# C++: influence library load order at runtime

Tags: c++, cmake, libjpeg

ubuntu 18.04 LTS as WSL, visual studio 16.6.0, cmake 3.10.
The question is about loading libraries at/prior to runtime, not at compile-time (at least i think so):

I work on an application, which writes a surface plot to a `jpeg` image and compares the image to a reference. the jpeg writer relies on `libjpeg.so`, while the comparison part relies on `libmwjpegreader.so`.

builds and compiles fine, but results in `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` upon execution, during the writing of the first jpeg file: apparently, both `libjpeg` as well as `libmwjpegreader` implement similar functions and for some reason, the jpeg writer uses `libmwjpegreader` functions instead of `libjpeg`'s.

the workaround is to prepend the launch of the executable with `LD_PRELOAD=libjpeg` , which results in the correct behavior. This is verified via `LD_DEBUG=files ./executable |& grep 'calling init'` - the load order of the libraries shifts and the application runs as intended.

any possibility to adjust the load order of the libraries *for execution*, without relying on `LD_PRELOAD`? Does it have any relationship with the linkage order during compile? I'm using `CMAKE` as my build environment, but including `libjpeg` or shifting positions in `cmakelists.txt` had no effect.

Comment: I *think* linking order should affect resulting executable, but it depends on linker itself. How do you build your program? Can we see build log (e.g. `make VERBOSE=1`  if you use make)? `readelf -d ./executable`?

Comment: tbh i rely on arcane IDE magic of visualstudio to build the project. i can offer [the cmakeoutput.log](https://gist.github.com/kamikatze13/72f69c75147bb02fd7fc8ec5a86df789).


my current understanding is that the executable has an `RPATH` attribute, which `ld.so` checks first during runtime and it can be modified via CMAKE. I have, however, not yet understood how to modify it appropriately

Comment: [`readelf -d ./executable`](https://gist.github.com/kamikatze13/91efd12cbec3b4f7696854f00b003653)

Comment: [order in which `ld` is calling init on the libraries](https://gist.github.com/kamikatze13/5a4ab1bbeeeb2953e31f688c6474c9c8)

Comment: I would avoid using libraries which exports same functions at any cost... Could comparison part of your application be moved into **separate executable**? Costs for running this separate executable from the main one could be a lesser evil than using conflicting libraries.

Comment: @kamikatze13 could you show `ldd ./executable` output as well? I suppose because of `--as-needed` linker flag you don't actually link to libjpeg at all? You can call some libjpeg-specific function to convince linker that you're actually using it (or remove as-needed flag). Of course the best way is to modify code to use only one library. You can also do some hacks like splitting your comparison code into separate dynamic library and `dlopen` it at runtime, after all automatic library loading is done. This is... not great at all.

Comment: [`ldd ./executable`](https://gist.github.com/kamikatze13/01ba469942a5e058ab4284d705a520f7).

true, i don't explicitly include `libjpeg` in `cmakelists.txt`, but even if i do, the result is the same.

as for using only one library - i wish i could. i cannot modify the image comparison code or `libmwjpegreader` because it is matlab code ported to c++ and `libmwjpegreader` can only read jpges, not write them. moving the comparison code to a separate executable would be ... undesirable at best. before i do that i'd write a custom launch script.

Comment: @kamikatze13 out of curiosity, are you preloading the same libjpeg that `libmwjpegreader` depends on, or different version? If you use libjpeg directly for your saving code, I don't see how `--as-needed` would have skipped that, may be your setup is more complicated than described. Sounds like `mwjpegreader` uses libjpeg internally? Is there a way to get it  updated to your current libjpeg version?

Comment: `libmwjpegreader` is (as far as i understand) an independent implementation and a complete blackbox given to me. [`readelf -d ./libmwjpegreader`](https://gist.github.com/kamikatze13/9fc1adeb0d16e6699e5864c0fa4ef42e) does not mention `libjpeg`, so i would say it doesn't depend on it. goes over my head why they are conflicting in the first place.